# Constructing an array of class attribute in a different class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have to do a project where one class  `Row`  has an array of integers `int* OneArray` and then another class `Array` has an array of the first class `Row* TwoDArray`.  In essence the class has a 2D array on integers, and I can easily do the construction of the 2D array when it is in one class. However, now I am completely stumped.

The construction of the `Row` is simple enough:

```
//set length of array
numOfRows = intRows;
//Create space for array
OneArray = new int[intRows];
//populate array with random numbers
for(int i=0; i<intRows; i++)
{
    OneArray[i] = GenerateRandom(9,0);
}
```

This is where I am stuck (Construction of `Array`):

```
//Set Number of Cols
NumOfCol = intCols;
//create length for each row
int intLength = 4;
for(int i=0; i<NumOfCol; i++)
{
    //create space and call row constructor with length
    TwoDArray = new Row(intLength);
    //increase length for jagged array
    intLength++;
}
```

As it is now it writes over the current array after each for loop (which is expected). So, I need to index `TwoDArray` like `TwoDArray[i]`, but as soon as I try to do that then I get this error:

"invalid user-defined conversion from 'Row*' to 'const Row&'."

Note: If I take the line out of the for loop only the first array is made and not until `intCol`.  `intLength` is increasing because I technically need a jagged array which has got different sizes in each array.

My classes look like this:

```
    class Row
{
    public:
        //Constructors
        Row();
        Row(int intRows);
        Row(const Row& objPrev);

        //Accessors
        int getNumOfRows();
        int getRowArray(int intRow);

        //Mutators
        void setRowArray(int intRow, int intChange);

        //Destructor
        ~Row();
    private:
        int* OneArray;
        int numOfRows;
}
```

and

```
 class Array
{
    public:
        //Constructors
        Array();
        Array(int intRows, int intCols);
        Array(const Array& objPrev);

        //Accessors
        int getNumOfCol();
        Row getTwoDArray(int intCol, int intRow);

        //Mutators
        void setTwoDArray(int intCol, int intRow, int intChageTo);

        //Destructor
        ~Array();
   private:
        Row* TwoDArray;
        int NumOfCol;
}
```

Any Help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: To begin with, please don't use pointers and `new[]` for arrays. If you want an "array" allocated at runtime use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), if you want an array with a fixed size at compiletime use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Then for your problem, if you want to continue using pointers and `new[]`: You should use `new[]` in `Array` as well. With `new Row(intLength)` you allocate a *single* `Row` object. And you should *not* do your allocation in a loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to use arrays and pointers because that is what the project is about.  The reason I called `new Row(intLength)` is because I have a constructor in `Row` with those parameters that creates a single array of integers.  Which is why I want to call that multiple times (as many as `intCols`)

Comment: "I need to index TwoDArray like TwoDArray[i], but as soon as I try to do that..."
which exact peace of code causes the error?

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko  where I try and call it like that in the for loop:
`for(int r=0; r<NumOfCol; r++)
    {
        //get the error here:
        TwoDArray[r] = new Row(intLength);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

With your loop in `Array` you allocate a single `Row` object multiple times, overwriting the pointer in each loop. That leads to a *memory leak* as only the last will be available through the variable `TwoDArray`. Also, at the end of the loop all you will have is an "array" of only a single element, the last allocated `Row` object.

The problem is that you can't do the array allocation using `new[]` at the same time as you call a specific constructor. You can **not** do e.g.

```
TwoDArray = new Row[NumOfCol](intLength);
```

Instead you have to split the allocation and initialization into two parts:

```
TwoDArray = new Row[NumOfCol];  // Allocates memory, default constructed Row objects

for (int i = 0; i < NumOfCol; ++i)
{
    TwoDArray[i] = Row(intLength);  // Initialize each element
}
```

This of course requires you follow the [rules of three or five (or zero)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for the copying in the loop to work.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)